# Is there a way to chain methods in JS where some methods are async?

Tags: javascript

We have a validation library like so..

```
const cache = [];

function rules(object) {

    return {
        addToCache(value) {
            cache.push(value)
        },
        minLengthStr(property, propertyAlias = property) { 
            const value = object[property];

            const message = 
                typeof value === 'string' && value.length > 2 ? null : `${propertyAlias} is less than 2`;
            cache.push(message);
            return rules(object);
        },

        emptyCollection(property, propertyAlias = property) {
            const value = object[property];

            const message = Array.isArray(value) && value.length <= 0 ?
               `${propertyAlias} collection is empty` : null

            cache.push(message);

            return rules(object);
        },

        isString(property, propertyAlias = property) { 
            debugger;
            const value = object[property];

            const message = typeof value === 'string' ? null : `${propertyAlias} is not a string`;
            cache.push(message);

            return rules(object);
        },

        value() {
            return cache.filter(Boolean);
        }   
    }
}


function validateRunner(value) {
    return rules(value)
}
```

You can call it like this...

```
const person = {
        website: 'google.com',
        name: 'Bi',
        age: '23',
        hobbies: [
            'running',
            'hiking'
        ]
    };

 const messages = validateRunner(person)
            .minLengthStr('name', 'eeeeee')
            .isString('name')
            .emptyCollection('hobbies')
            .value()


      console.log(messages)
```

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/stoplion/pen/yWYGaV?editors=1112)

This has worked well so far.
But now we need to add some checks that are async..

For example, the `OKUrl` method..

```
let cache = [];


function fetchIt(url) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const message = /http/.test(url) ? `${url} is ok` : null;
      res(message);
    }, 3000)
  })
}


function rules(object) {

  return {
    addToCache(value) {
      cache.push(value)
    },

    async okURL(property, propertyAlias = property) {
      const message = await fetchIt(property);
      return rules(object);
    },

    minLengthStr(property, propertyAlias = property) {
      const value = object[property];

      const message =
        typeof value === 'string' && value.length > 2 ? null : `${propertyAlias} is less than 2`;
      cache.push(message);
      return rules(object);
    },

    emptyCollection(property, propertyAlias = property) {
      const value = object[property];

      const message = Array.isArray(value) && value.length <= 0 ?
        `${propertyAlias} collection is empty` : null

      cache.push(message);

      return rules(object);
    },

    isString(property, propertyAlias = property) {
      debugger;
      const value = object[property];

      const message = typeof value === 'string' ? null : `${propertyAlias} is not a string`;
      cache.push(message);

      return rules(object);
    },

    value() {
      return cache.filter(Boolean);
    }
  }
}


function validateRunner(value) {
  return rules(value)
}


const person = {
  website: 'google.com',
  name: 'Bi',
  age: '23',
  hobbies: [
    'running',
    'hiking'
  ]
};


const messages = validateRunner(person)
  .minLengthStr('name', 'eeeeee')
  .isString('name')
  .emptyCollection('hobbies')
  .okURL('website')
  .value()


console.log(messages)
```

[WIP Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/stoplion/pen/byVOwN?editors=1112) (This example does not work — just a WIP)

Is it possible to have a chainable structure like this with one or two async methods? Or does it call for totally changing the way its called?

Comment: Please go through this once http://javascript.info/microtask-queue

Might help.

Comment: okURL function will not return the `rules(object)` till the fetch is complete. But fetch calls setTimeout which is a macro task (low priority). You should use Promise.all API for this use case (each function can be called in async, once converted to a Promise).

Comment: How would you use promise.all for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let cache = [];

let minLengthStr = function(object, property, propertyAlias = property) {
                 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                      const value = object[property];
                      const message = typeof value === 'string' && value.length > 2 ? null : `${propertyAlias} is less than 2`;
                      cache.push(message);
                          resolve();
                  });
 };


let emptyCollection = function(object,property, propertyAlias = property) {
                 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                      const value = object[property];
                      const message = (Array.isArray(value) && value.length <= 0) ? `${propertyAlias} collection is empty` : null;
                      cache.push(message);
                          resolve();
                  });
        };

 let isString = function(object,property, propertyAlias = property) {
                 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                      const value = object[property];
                      const message = typeof value === 'string' ? null : `${propertyAlias} is not a string`;
                      cache.push(message);
                          resolve();
                  });
        }


  let okURL = function(object,property, propertyAlias = property) {
                 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                       const value = object[property];
                       const message = /http/.test(value) ? `${value} is ok` : null;
                       cache.push(message);                
                       resolve();
                  });
  }


function validateRunner(value) {
    Promise.all([minLengthStr(value,'name','fakeName'), emptyCollection(value,'hobbies', 'fakeHobbies'), isString(value,'name', 'dummyString'), okURL(value, 'website', 'fakeWebsite')]).then(function() {
      console.log('All completed', cache.filter(Boolean));
    });
}


const person = {
        website: 'google.com',
        name: null,
        age: '23',
        hobbies: []
    };


validateRunner(person);
```

Comment: ahh i see, return promise for all rules.